# Find best image similarity based on color palette

Tags: php, mysql

I have this little script for demonstration
http://www.predajdielo.sk/tmp.similar.php?source_image=1
(you can change source image via source_image $_GET parameter from 1 to 10)

I have database with thousands of images. Each image has precomputed color palette that is stored in the format 999999,666666,333333,cccccc,666633,000000,..etc in the database. Each pallet contains information of 16 colors and this palette is sorted by most used colors in the picture.

What way to find the most closely related pictures via database query according to source image? My solution is not very effective :(

```
SELECT
 item.*,
 MATCH (item.image_digital_hash) AGAINST ('+996666 +999999 +cc9999 +996633 +666699 +666666 +669999 +663333 +999966 +330000 +666633 +ffffff +9999cc +663300 +333333 +000000') AS score
FROM item
INNER JOIN user ON item.user_id = user.id
WHERE
 user.account_status = 'ok' AND
 item.status = 'ok' AND
 item.categorization LIKE '%%umelecka-tvorba,obrazy%%' AND 
 item.image_digital_hash IS NOT NULL AND
 item.image_digital_hash LIKE '996666%%' AND
 MATCH (item.image_digital_hash) AGAINST ('+996666 +999999 +cc9999 +996633 +666699 +666666 +669999 +663333 +999966 +330000 +666633 +ffffff +9999cc +663300 +333333 +000000')
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your solution? This is Stack Overflow. Code is pretty much mandatory.

Comment: My solution is in the attached URL, but i edit my post

Comment: Depending on an external link is bad form for a question here. That code helps a lot.

Comment: I wrote something similar once. I wonder what I did with it...

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - although I fear your schema may require some redesign

Answer (score 0):

OK, i've been thinking a bit about the question, how find as many related images based on using the palette of the source image.

The answer is not that difficult. It`s about logic :)
First.. Every color has own position, so we use MySql LOCATE function to find number of position relative to source color code. Check if color code exists and if not, add max possible number which is 7*16 = 112. This we make for each color from source image.

Then it is enough just sort results based on the sum of retrieved positions. The results are images with the closest possible color palette.

Not so nice or clear SQL query, but it works fine

```
SELECT
    item.*,
    IF (LOCATE ('996699', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('996699', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_1, 
    IF (LOCATE ('999999', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('999999', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_2, 
    IF (LOCATE ('cccccc', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('cccccc', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_3, 
    IF (LOCATE ('cc99cc', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('cc99cc', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_4, 
    IF (LOCATE ('333333', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('333333', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_5, 
    IF (LOCATE ('666699', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('666699', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_6, 
    IF (LOCATE ('663399', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('663399', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_7, 
    IF (LOCATE ('663366', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('663366', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_8, 
    IF (LOCATE ('9966cc', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('9966cc', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_9, 
    IF (LOCATE ('ffffff', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('ffffff', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_10, 
    IF (LOCATE ('9999cc', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('9999cc', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_11, 
    IF (LOCATE ('cc9999', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('cc9999', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_12, 
    IF (LOCATE ('996666', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('996666', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_13, 
    IF (LOCATE ('666666', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('666666', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_14, 
    IF (LOCATE ('ffcccc', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('ffcccc', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_15, 
    IF (LOCATE ('663333', item.image_digital_hash) > 0, LOCATE ('663333', item.image_digital_hash), 112) AS tmp_16

FROM item

INNER JOIN user ON item.user_id = user.id

WHERE
    user.account_status = 'ok' AND
    item.status = 'ok' AND
    item.categorization LIKE '%%umelecka-tvorba,obrazy%%' AND
    item.image_digital_hash IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY (tmp_1 + tmp_2 + tmp_3 + tmp_4 + tmp_5 + tmp_6 + tmp_7 + tmp_8 + tmp_9 + tmp_10 + tmp_11 + tmp_12 + tmp_13 + tmp_14 + tmp_15 + tmp_16) ASC

LIMIT 100
```

Demonstration here http://www.predajdielo.sk/tmp.similar.done.php?source_image=9
(you can ofcourse change source image via source_image $_GET parameter from 1 to 10)